# Scroll View in android activity

Tags: android, android-layout, scrollview, android-scrollview

I ahve made a simple activity in that i have used scrollView but its not working and shows error,so i have removed scrollView..Friends i need is all the menus should be included to scrollView..Please can anyone suggest me wher7e should i place the "scrollView" tag in my activity.

my activity is as below:
[image]

**main-menu.xml**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:orientation="vertical">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:src="@drawable/kevingreen" android:background="#000" android:layout_weight="1"/>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout2"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="0.3"
        android:background="#fffff3"
        android:orientation="vertical" >



        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/linearLayout4"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="190dp" >

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/linearLayout6"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:orientation="vertical" >

                <ImageButton
                    android:id="@+id/imageButtonVideos"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="115dp"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                    android:background="#0000"
                    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                    android:src="@drawable/balcony_pic" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView1"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:text="Videos"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMediumInverse"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/linearLayout7"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:orientation="vertical" >

                <ImageButton
                    android:id="@+id/ImageButtonTraining2"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                    android:background="#0000"
                    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                    android:src="@drawable/crowd_pic" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/TextView02"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="0.6"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:text="Training"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMediumInverse"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/linearLayout8"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:orientation="vertical" >

                <ImageButton
                    android:id="@+id/ImageButtonCalculator"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="94dp"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                    android:background="#0000"
                    android:scaleType="fitCenter"
                    android:src="@drawable/calculator" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/TextView01"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="0.6"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:text="Property Calculator"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMediumInverse"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />
            </LinearLayout>

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/linearLayout5"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="148dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp" >

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/LinearLayout01"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:orientation="vertical" >

                <ImageButton
                    android:id="@+id/ImageButtonShop"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="77dp"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
                    android:background="#0000"
                    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                    android:src="@drawable/compra" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/TextView03"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:text="Shop"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMediumInverse"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/LinearLayout02"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:orientation="vertical" >

                <ImageButton
                    android:id="@+id/ImageButtonAboutKevin"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="82dp"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
                    android:background="#0000"
                    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                    android:src="@drawable/about_me_pic" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/TextView04"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:text="About Kevin"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMediumInverse"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/LinearLayout03"
                android:layout_width="84dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:orientation="vertical" >

                <ImageButton
                    android:id="@+id/ImageButtonLinks"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="88dp"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
                    android:background="#0000"
                    android:scaleType="fitCenter"
                    android:src="@drawable/coaching_pic" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/TextView05"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="0.88"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:text="Social"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMediumInverse"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

            </LinearLayout>

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/linearLayoutthird"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="102dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp" >

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/LinearLayoutsubthird"
                android:layout_width="298dp"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:layout_weight="0.83"
                android:orientation="vertical" >

                <ImageButton
                    android:id="@+id/ImageButtonBlog"
                    android:layout_width="130dp"
                    android:layout_height="102dp"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                    android:background="#0000"
                    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                    android:src="@drawable/blogger" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/TextViewblogger"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:text="Blogger"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMediumInverse"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/LinearLayoutabout"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:orientation="vertical" >
                <LinearLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:id="@+id/LinearLayoutabout" android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:layout_marginBottom="10dp" android:layout_marginTop="10dp" android:layout_weight="1" android:orientation="vertical">
                    <ImageButton android:id="@+id/ImageButtonContactUs" android:layout_width="130dp" android:layout_height="102dp" android:layout_marginBottom="10dp" android:layout_marginLeft="10dp" android:layout_marginRight="10dp" android:layout_marginTop="40dp" android:background="#0000" android:scaleType="centerCrop" android:src="@drawable/contact_us_478x318"/>
                    <TextView android:id="@+id/TextViewcontactus" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:layout_weight="1" android:gravity="center" android:text="Contact Us" android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMediumInverse" android:textStyle="bold"/>
                </LinearLayout>

                <ImageButton
                    android:id="@+id/ImageButtonContactUs"
                    android:layout_width="130dp"
                    android:layout_height="182dp"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
                    android:background="#0000"
                    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                    android:src="@drawable/contact_us_478x318" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/TextViewcontactus"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:text="Contact Us"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMediumInverse"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout3"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:layout_weight="1" android:background="@drawable/gradient_grey">
        <LinearLayout 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1" android:orientation="vertical">
        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/imageButtonHome"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:src="@drawable/g3570" android:layout_weight="0.6" android:background="#0000" android:scaleType="fitCenter" android:layout_marginTop="5dp"/>

        <TextView                 android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
             android:layout_weight="1"
             android:text="Home"
            android:gravity="center" android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMediumInverse" android:textColor="#fff" android:textStyle="bold"/>

        </LinearLayout> <LinearLayout 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1" android:orientation="vertical">

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/imageButtonTraining"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:src="@drawable/g4404" android:layout_weight="0.6" android:scaleType="fitCenter" android:background="#0000" android:layout_marginTop="5dp"/>
            <TextView                 android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
             android:layout_weight="1"
             android:text="Training"
            android:gravity="center" android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMediumInverse" android:textColor="#fff" android:textStyle="bold"/>

        </LinearLayout> <LinearLayout 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1" android:orientation="vertical">
        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/imageButtonContactUs"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:src="@drawable/icon_email" android:layout_weight="0.6" android:scaleType="fitCenter" android:background="#0000" android:layout_marginTop="5dp"/>
           <TextView                 android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
             android:layout_weight="1"
             android:text="Contact Us"
            android:gravity="center" android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMediumInverse" android:textColor="#fff" android:textStyle="bold"/>

        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Please tell me where should i place scrollView tag so that it will work properly..Thank you in advance.!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Put all your views in a parent layout and then add ScrollView to that parent layout in xml. As ScrollView can be added to only one child. Hope this helps.

Comment: @newBee-can i put multiple linearlayouts in a single scrollView?

Comment: Yes you can, provided you wrap those multiple layouts in a single parent layout say relative or linear and then put that parent into scrollview.
Remember you can add as many as views but wrap them in a single parent to get a scrollview over that.

Answer (score 0):

Place the `<ScrollView>` after first `<ImageView>` tag and place your menu items in a single `<LinearLayout>` tag as ScrollView works only for a single child.